# Can't use yum inside Docker container running on CentOS

Tags: docker, centos, containers, sudo, yum

I am unable to run any yum commands inside my Docker container without getting the following error:

```
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/Group'
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

I'm confused because I'm pretty sure docker containers are run with the default user root.  Still, if I try putting sudo in front of a `yum install -y <package>` or `yum update -y` command I get:

```
/bin/sh: sudo: command not found
```

I'm using the following base image so I can easily run a Java Wildfly application inside Docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/

The underlying distro is `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`

Comment: I don't think sudo is in the base images by default.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Turns out the user was set to `jboss` in the base image.
When is switched to user root with the dockerfile command `USER root` everything worked.

Comment: Got this running `centos/nodejs-6-centos7`... What a shame!

Comment: Ditto on `centos/python-36-centos7`

Comment: after switching to `root` to perform `yum` step, should you change it back to the original user? In your case `jboss`

Comment: Yeah, switching to ROOT is likely a security concern.  Check out this thread for better docker user management: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957722/4447761