# Docker permission denied via build image for container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I tried to build image from Dockerfile. 
For this purposes I used this dockerhub image: https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin-haproxy-router

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openshift/origin-haproxy-router
RUN INSTALL_PKGS="haproxy18 rsyslog" && \
                  yum install -y $INSTALL_PKGS && \
                  yum clean all && \
                  rpm -V $INSTALL_PKGS && \
                  mkdir -p /var/lib/haproxy/router/{certs,cacerts,whitelists} && \
                  mkdir -p /var/lib/haproxy/{conf/.tmp,run,bin,log} && \
                  touch /var/lib/haproxy/conf/{{os_http_be,os_edge_reencrypt_be,os_tcp_be,os_sni_passthrough,os_route_http_redirect,cert_config,os_wildcard_domain}.map,haproxy.config} && \
                  setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=ep' /usr/sbin/haproxy && \
                  chown -R :0 /var/lib/haproxy && \
                  chmod -R g+w /var/lib/haproxy
COPY images/router/haproxy/* /var/lib/haproxy/
LABEL io.k8s.display-name="OpenShift HAProxy Router" \
  io.k8s.description="This component offers ingress to an OpenShift cluster via Ingress and Route rules." \
  io.openshift.tags="openshift,router,haproxy"
USER root
EXPOSE 80 443
WORKDIR /var/lib/haproxy/conf
ENV TEMPLATE_FILE=/var/lib/haproxy/conf/haproxy-config.template \
RELOAD_SCRIPT=/var/lib/haproxy/reload-haproxy
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/openshift-router"]
```

After I tried to run command inside folder with dockerfile:

```
sudo docker build -t os-router .
```

I got next result:

```
 ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/Conflictname'
 You need to be root to perform this command.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133849/cant-use-yum-inside-docker-container-running-on-centos

Comment: duplicate names are conficting please check

Comment: @Arpit, be careful, when you read my Dockerfile, please, this one doesn't work for me!

Comment: At what stage does the error occur?

Comment: @NikitaLitvinov it would be great if you can also tell us what you have tried and failed so people stop posting basic answers for your problem.

Comment: @NikitaLitvinov also why don't you try putting the `USER root` at the 2nd line of your dockerfile before installing the packages through yum?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal, when I changed the position of USER root, I got stuck with following expression "Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors.  .......P /usr/sbin/haproxy .M....G.. /var/lib/haproxy". It can't move forward

Answer (score 0):

put  `USER root` in your dockerfile